# Finding boundaries of triple integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the boundaries for $x$, $y$, $z$ of a region bounded by $z^2 \leq x^2+y^2$ and $z\leq 2-x^2-y^2$.

Setup in the solution:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^1\rho d\rho\ \int_{-ρ}^{ρ}dz + \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta $\int_1^2\rho d\rho\ \int_{-ρ}^{2-ρ^2}dz$$

I don't understand why is integral split into 2 pieces. Please help.

Comment: I really don't like keeping the variable names $x$ and $y$ after converting to polar.   Anyway, since you are integrating with respect to $z$ first, there is a portion of the region where z is bound by the paraboloid above and a portion that is bounded by the cone above.  If you integrate with respect to $r$ (or $\rho$) first you can do this with one integral.

Comment: Shouldn't we then multiply the answer by 2,because there are 2 same regions?

Comment: One really needs to draw a picture and not fall in traps. No matter which order of integration you use, you will need two integrals. Either you consider $0\le \rho\le 1$ and $1\le \rho\le 2$ or, perhaps a little easier, you consider $0\le z\le 1$ and $-2\le z\le 0$. When you say "2 same regions," remember that $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$ and the region is one connected piece — even though a vertical cross-section has two symmetric pieces.

Comment: As @Ninad commented to me (in the mistaken answer I have now removed), you could be slick and combine the integrals into one in the other order: You might be clever and write $\int_{-2}^1 dz\int_{|z|}^{\sqrt{2-z}}d\rho$ rather than writing $\int_{-2}^0 dz\int_{-z}^{\sqrt{2-z}} + \int_0^1 dz\int_z^{\sqrt{2-z}}d\rho$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was going to make a silly comment about using the antiderivative of $|x|$, but I just realized that the integrand has a $\rho\:d\rho$ so using the silly one integral phrasing of $\rho = |z|$ might actually be a simple solution the original solution writer overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is split into two pieces for the following reason:

The two conditions $z^2\le x^2+y^2\,,\; z\le 2-x^2-y^2\,,$ can be written in cylindrical coordinates as

\begin{align}\tag{1}
-\rho\le z\le \rho\,,\quad z\le 2-\rho^2\,,\quad \rho\in[0,2]\,.
\end{align}
Note that $-\rho\le 2-\rho^2$  leads to $\rho\in[0,2]\,.$

When $\rho\in[0,1]$ the condition $-\rho\le z\le \rho$ is stronger and $z\le 2-\rho^2$ can be dropped:
Then (1) becomes
$$\tag{1a}\boxed{\quad
-\rho\le z\le\rho\,,\quad\rho\in[0,1]\,.\phantom{\Big|}\quad}
$$
This is the first piece.

When $\rho\in[1,2]$ then $z\le 2-\rho^2$ is stronger than $z\le\rho$ and (1) can be written as
$$\tag{1b}
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}-\rho\le z\le 2-\rho^2\,.\quad\rho\in[1,2]\,.\quad}
$$
This is the second piece.

The respective regions we integrate over are denoted by $I$ and $II$ in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a picture-free careful analysis. But why are you writing $<$ rather than $\le$? That messes up your closed interval.

Comment: @TedShifrin The picture took a bit longer. Hopefully all $<$ are eliminated also now.

Comment: Noticed that the left half of the picture must go. Will edit.

Comment: @KurtG. I have an easy to edit plot from Desmos that might suit your needs: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4aqoc0gh5z

Feel free to play with it to give you the picture you want as well since I limited the boundaries to only the parts of the curves that touch the domain of integration. And another plot with the full curves: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aeoiz8t5qw You can toggle the shading on or off by canceling the last two inequalities.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks! Will do. This is a combination of GeogeBra and Paint. Very inconvenient.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This can be set up as one integral in spherical coordinates. Converting the boundaries we get

$$\begin{cases}z^2=x^2+y^2 \\ z = 2-x^2-y^2\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\theta = \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4} \\ r = \frac{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+8\sin^2\theta}-\cos\theta}{2\sin^2\theta} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{8-7\cos^2\theta}-\cos\theta}\end{cases}$$

which gives us the bounds

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\sin\theta\:d\theta\int_0^{\frac{4}{\sqrt{8-7\cos^2\theta}-\cos\theta}}r^2\:dr$$

Of course, doing it with angular integral first would be easier but would still result in two integrals, and at that point if the number of integrals cannot be reduced the computation is much simpler in cylindrical coordinates. For questions that only ask to setup the bounds for a generic integral and never compute them, it is good to know that it is possible to write the integral in one piece.

---

$\textbf{Edit:}$ The other answer clearly explains why doing the $z$ integral first results in needing to split the integral into two pieces because of the changing upper bound. With @TedShifrin's help, we realized could have written this as one integral by doing the $\rho$ integral first. Rewriting the bounds we have

$$z^2 = x^2+y^2 \implies |z| = \sqrt{z^2} = \sqrt{\rho^2} = \rho$$

since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, not $x$. However the absolute values are not necessary on $\rho$ because by definition, the radial coordinate cannot be negative. Thus we have our boundaries

$$|z| \leq \rho \leq \sqrt{2-z}$$

again only taking the positive branch of the square root for the RHS bound. This gives us the one integral setup

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{-2}^1 dz \int_{|z|}^{\sqrt{2-z}}\rho\:d\rho$$

Ordinarily you would have to split up $|z|$ as a piecewise function and this would have become a two integral problem again. However if carry forward the computation anyway

$$ = \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{-2}^1\left[\frac{1}{2}\rho^2\right]_{|z|}^{\sqrt{2-z}}dz = \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{-2}^11 - \frac{1}{2}(z+z^2)\:dz = \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

and the piecewise nature of the absolute value never came up. This was a fascinatingly simple solution the original solution writer overlooked (and I don't blame them, the bounds and the integrands lining up this nicely with these specific functions usually doesn't happen in standard Calculus III problem design).